# NPM Dependency from google repository

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, google-cloud-repository

I have a Google Cloud Repository, let's say:

```
https://source.developers.google.com/p/blablan/r/blabla-common
```

now I wanted to add this repo as a dependency to another project, so i ran

```
 npm install git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/blablan/r/blabla-commo#r-01 --save
```

which worked great. but now I want to deploy it and I need to find a way to add the credentials to the dependency, but I can't find how.

how do I add the credentials to the dependency from google cloud? and do I use username+password or can I generate a token?